# how to do a dynamic boolean checking in xslt

Tags: xslt

From my root template for unique account value, call goes to trans template were in the input xml I will have multiple nodes, my requirement is that once the call goes from root template to trans template, if a match of accountId found in between multiple elements, account details template is called only once, irrespective of other match found. I need a solution for above requirement.

input sample :

```
  <elements><accountId>1</accountId></elements>
  <elements><accountId>1</accountId></elements>
  <elements><accountId>2</accountId></elements>
  <elements><accountId>2</accountId></elements>
  <elements><accountId>3</accountId></elements>
```

The below line should be wrapped under some code so its called only once

```
<xsl:call-template name="Account_details" />
```

Below is my complete code for xsl

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:variable name="unique-accounts" select="//*/*/*/accountId/text()[generate-id()=generate-id(key('account-by-id', .)[1])]"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="$unique-accounts">
             <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="current()"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//trans">
                <xsl:with-param name="passCurrentValue" select="$currentValue"/>
                 </xsl:apply-templates>
         </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="trans"> 
    <xsl:param name="passCurrentValue" />
    <xsl:variable name="booleanValue" select="true()"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="elements">
                <xsl:if test="$passCurrentValue=/*/*/accountId">
                    <xsl:if test="$booleanValue">
                        <xsl:call-template name="Account_details" />
                        <xsl:variable name="booleanValue" select="false()"></xsl:variable>
                    </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Account_details">
.............
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you are using XSLT 1.0 then, XSLT 1.0 doesn't support changing value of variable after assignment

Comment: oh...is there any way to check that the piece of code is executing first time...like adding counter or something

Comment: @Brittas Why don't you show us the big picture of what you're trying to accmplish here - instead of focusing on micro-code that doesn't work (and cannot work in XSLT)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k hi I have updated the question, now I guess you can help me with solution for my requirement.

Comment: @Brittas No, I meant the BIG picture; what is your ultimate purpose here? You start with 5 accounts. What do you want to have in the end?  I see you already know how to use *Muenchian grouping* to reduce them to the 3 distinct ones only; what else are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

With the code

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="booleanCheck" select="true"></xsl:variable>
```

the variable `booleanCheck` is a node-set (XSLT 1.0) or sequence of elements named `true` below the document node `/`. So unless your XML input has a root element named `true` the value is an empty node-set respectively empty sequence. If you want to select a boolean value then use `<xsl:variable name="booleanValue" select="true()"/>`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-true. Then you can test `<xsl:if test="$booleanValue">`. That should explain how to use boolean values, whether that fits into your context I am not sure.